# Show that there is only one conic passing through the five points $[0:0:1], [0:1:0],[1:0:0],[1:1:1]$ and $[1:2:3]$. Show that it is nonsingular

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Show that there is only one conic passing through the five points $[0:0:1], [0:1:0],[1:0:0],[1:1:1]$ and $[1:2:3]$.

Show that it is nonsingular

Comment: Write down the homogeneous quadratic form defining the general conic. (It has 6 coefficients). Evalaute it at the 5 given points, and set the result equal to 0. This gives 5 homogeneous linear equations in 6 variables. Check the solution space is 1-dimensional. So the forms are all proportional, hence all define the same conic. Check that the forms aren't a product of two linear factors.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh What do these points mean? Does the pass through these points?? Will the general equation look like $aX^2+2hXY+bY^2+2gX+2fY+c-Z=0$??

Comment: These are points in the projective plane. If you don't know what that means, you should go back and learn the basics before trying to solve this problem. Your general equation isn't quite right because it isn't _homogeneous_. Again, if you don't know why that's a problem, read over the basics of projective space.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Can you please solve it??

Comment: Concerning "Can you please solve it?": Asal Beag Dubh can certainly solve it, but I think that before showing you the solution, he should wait until there is evidence that you have learned enough of the prerequisites to understand a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since no three of the five points are aligned, any conic through the five points is non-singular.